# .isin() returning a blank dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc, isin

My DataFrame:

[image: My Dataframe]

Trying...

[image: Does not work]

Nope...

[image: Does not work]

Still nope...

[image]

AND YET...

[image: Huh?]

Any idea why I can't filter this dataframe by a list using isin?

I'm expecting it to return one or more rows where the Chord Notes column equals the list ['C','E','G']

Comment: Don't make us retype code from an image.  Please post all code, input, output, and error messages as plain text.

Comment: reason being that column contains a actual list objects

Comment: You need to put the list ['C', 'E', 'G'] inside a list, like [['C', 'E', 'G']]

Comment: Anurag, so how would you solve?

Comment: Thank you lucas, your answer was correct as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can still use `isin()` but since the values under 'Chord Notes' are actual list object so you have to pass that list object i.e `['C','E','G']` in `isin()` method

```
output = full_chords[full_chords['Chord Notes'].isin([['C','E','G']])]
```

Or with `map()` (kind of loop under the hood):

```
output = full_chords[full_chords['Chord Notes'].map(lambda x:x==['C','E','G'])]
```

Or

Other way around is to typecast that column to string(not recommended but still an option tho):

```
output = full_chords[full_chords['Chord Notes'].astype(str).eq("['C','E','G']")]
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly and the logic makes sense.